# How to authenticate a asp.net application user to share point site

Tags: sharepoint-server, asp.net

In our organisation we published a asp.net mvc application in internet , and other side

also we have a share point internet portal.

for asp.net mvc application :

here every authenticated user login to asp.net mvc application ,

every registered user and authenticated user stored  in sql server database.

for share point :

share point application has enabled claims authentication and not allow anonymous log in for  users

and a specific group of active directory users only has permissions to view this share point portal.

Here in mvc application there is a service to view the some BI  data  and this data is in sharepoint web application

here how i connect  authenticated mvc application user  to view the BI data in sharepoint?

Answer (score 1):

You can prompt user to enter SP credentials. Or, you do not even need the mvc app authentication and use directly the SP one - just prompt the window with login, check if the user was authenticated and use this for mvc app access and SP BI access.

Or, go the claims way and [configure STS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff955607%28v=office.14%29.aspx#sp14ClaimsExample1_OverviewofTrustedLoginProvider)

Comment: the first step is external user login to asp.net mvc application and authenticated using farms authentication , and after that how i will authenticate same user to sharepoinit web application and it is claims based authentication enalbe.